# Create a graph from a csv file using a dictionary

Tags: python, graph

I'm trying to do an academic project (I cannot use any of the libraries from python) to construct a graph data structure from teh data in a csv file.

First I'm reading the csv file and put the information into a dictionary, using:

```
def github_csv():
    with open('Github1.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        data = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        next(data)
        for row in data:
            print(row)
```

The output is:

```
{'follower': '9236', 'followed': '1570'}
{'follower': '13256', 'followed': '9236'}
{'follower': '9236', 'followed': '13256'}
```

My first doubt is there any way to put it like this:

```
'9236': ['1570', '13256']
'13256': ['9236']
```

Then how can I assign the key value to a vertex and corresponding values for another vertex and then create the edges?
My graph class is:

```
class Graph:
        
    def __init__(self, directed=False):
        self._directed = directed
        self._number = 0           
        self._vertices = {}         

    def insert_vertex(self, x):
        v = Vertex(x)
        self._vertices[v] = {}     
        self._number = len(self._vertices)
        return v

    def insert_edge(self, u, v, x=None):
        e = Edge(u, v, x)
        self._vertices[u][v] = e  
        self._vertices[v][u] = e
```

EDIT:

```
class Vertex:

    __slots__ = "_element"

    def __init__(self, x):
        self._element = x

    def vertice(self):
        return self._element

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Vertex):
            return self._element == other.vertice()
        return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self._element)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(id(self))  


class Edge:

    __slots__ = '_origin', '_destination', '_weight'

    def __init__(self, u, v, p=None):
        self._origin = u
        self._destination = v
        self._weight = p

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self._origin, self._destination))

    def __repr__(self):
        if self._weight is None:
            return '({0}, {1})'.format(self._origin, self._destination)
        return '({0}, {1}, {2})'.format(self._origin, self._destination, self._weight)

    def endpoints(self):
        return self._origin, self._destination

    def opposite(self, v):
        return self._origin if v is self._destination else self._origin

    def cost(self):
        return self._weight

    def show_edge(self):
        print('(', self._origin, ', ', self._destination, ') com peso', self._weight)
```

Comment: @martineau, class Vertex and class Edge added to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first question:

```
lista = [{'follower': '9236', 'followed': '1570'},
{'follower': '13256', 'followed': '9236'},
{'follower': '9236', 'followed': '13256'}]

rel_dict = {}
for d in lista:
    if d["follower"] in rel_dict.keys():
        rel_dict[d["follower"]].append(d["followed"])
    else:
        rel_dict[d["follower"]] = [d["followed"]]
```

rel_dict:

```
{'9236': ['1570', '13256'], '13256': ['9236']}
```

EDIT2 (with Vertex and Edge definition):

To add these data to the graph:

```
graph = Graph()
for k,v in rel_dict.items():
    k_vertex = graph.insert_vertex(k)
    for v_item in v:
        v_item_vertex = graph.insert_vertex(v_item)
        graph.insert_edge(k_vertex, v_item_vertex)
```

Comment: class Vertex and class Edge added to the code.

Comment: @SandraSilva: to print it it's better to use __str__, __repr__ is for internal representation. To print it in while debugging you can print(graph.__dict__)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you get `row` as the dictionaries you've mentioned,

```
edges_dict = {}
def github_csv():
with open('Github1.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    data = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    next(data)
    for row in data:
        edges_dict[ row['follower'] ].append(row['followed'])
```

This should give you an `edges_dict` dictionary of lists as required.

Comment: the followeds are given in multiple row, in this way you overwrite the past rows resulting in a single followed for each follower

Comment: @frab, thanks a lot for the help. Wich is better to print the resulting graph? Create a __repr__ method?

Comment: @frab could you help me again in another topic? Is there anyway I can adress you my doubts?